# Unable set the limit of visible options in the dropdown of a select input type

Tags: javascript, css, select, html-select, dropdownbox

Please see my form here. https://business-sale.com/daily-companies-finance-alerts#dfa-form

As you can see when you click on the drop-down menu the dropdown menu opens upwards (instead of downwards) and sends the user to the top of the page. Which is problematic especially if the user uses a small screen. I assume the reason is it has too many options. I have nearly 1000s options in my select dropdown box. I want to limit the visible options to 10. And make the drop-down box scrollable.

I have tried this

```html
<select class="selectpicker" id="sector" name="sector" multiple
        style="height: 10px; overflow-y: scroll;"
        data-live-search="true"
        onfocus="this.size=10;">
```

and

```html
<select class="selectpicker" id="sector" name="sector" multiple
        style="height: 10px; overflow-y: scroll;"
        data-live-search="true"
        onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}">
```

But it's not working.

For the rest of the code please check here

https://jsfiddle.net/bashabi/8fqmuyea/5/

How to fix it

Comment: Maybe not related, but that page is throwing an error when clicking the dropdown:
`dropdowntoggle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at toggleDropDown (dropdowntoggle.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (VM149 daily-companies-finance-alerts:174)`

Comment: Since you're using bootstrap why not use their custom dropdown ? [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43863487/7148391)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i am using bootstrap select; The solution of limiting the visible option lies here

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-size="5">
  ...
</select>
```

So in my case

```
 <select class="selectpicker" id="sector" name="sector" multiple
        style="height: 10px; overflow-y: scroll;"
        data-live-search="true"
        data-size="10">
```

Reference : https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your script to override as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20503446/1762224). This will force the dropdown to always be a "drop-down".

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    dropupAuto: false
});
```

The global default can be overridden as well.

```js
$.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.dropupAuto = false;
```

Also, check out:

- https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#dropup-menu
- [bootstrap drop-down menu auto dropup according to screen position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232685/bootstrap-drop-down-menu-auto-dropup-according-to-screen-position)

Comment: Thank you. added the script but still drops up. not drop down.

Comment: @Bashabi I literally threw it at the end of your JSFiddle example and re-ran it and it worked.

Comment: in the js fiddle, it always drops down. Even without the script. Probably because of the screen position.

Comment: In the select .bootstrap .js its set up as  -   dropupAuto: !0,

Comment: @Bashabi In JavaScript, `!0` is `true`... it's a fancy way to spare typing two more letters. You need to override it to `false` or `!!0` ;)